# Fail install compass in Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: ruby, terminal, compass

I am trying to install compass via terminal from Mac OS X 10.10, but I didn't do this, I saw many article that people have problem during the instal in this OS, anybody help me to install compass ? Below this comment will be the link from pastebin with the content for return command gem install compass.

http://pastebin.com/Uyn5K8W6

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

t looks like maybe your Mac doesn't have xcode command line tools installed. Try this in the terminal then try installing again:

`xcode-select --install`

You will also need to accept the license agreement. I think it asks you automatically now.

Answer (score 0):

In case your development log states:

```
"You have to install development tools first."
```

Install xcode by running the following command:

```
`xcode-select --install`
```